# jQuery jScrollPane not working with div percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jscrollpane

I am working with jScrollPane to create a custom scrollbar. I have a bunch of div's that lineup horizontally. For some reason, when I use percentage instead of a fixed width, the scrollbar does not show up, but if I change it to a fixed width it will work.

[**Percentage**](https://jsfiddle.net/px6mzhgp/)

```
.productsimilarproduct {
    width: 30%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}
```

[**Fixed Width**](https://jsfiddle.net/px6mzhgp/1/)

```
.productsimilarproduct {
    width: 288px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

This issue isn't listed in the [known bugs](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/known_issues.html) for jScrollPane, so I thought I'd post this up on StackOverflow to see if anyone knew of a solution.

Is there anyway for me to set the width of my div's to a percentage and still use jScrollPane?